# How to hide file name in url

Tags: php

I have a problem to hide file name in url using .htaccess my code is working properly but it hide only .php.
    example :

```
<a href="userlogin.php">User Login </a>

After click on link like this in current URL is url
http://thereliableservices.in/userlogin.php

htaccess code here .....

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

After using htaccess code url like
   User Login 
   http://thereliableservices.in/userlogin

but I want like in Url :  http://thereliableservices.in/   after click on User Login

Thanks for great help

Comment: Why does it matter if the filename forms part fof the URL?

Comment: If the url does not contain the page name, how is the server going to distinguish between pages?

Comment: If you want your URL to stay the same at all time, you need to switch to an AJAX based solution or load everything in an iframe (yuck!) ... In general I just wouldn't recommend doing any of this, because deeplinking pages is an important part of usability, especially at the moment when people share links to all of their friends using social media.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace anything you want, but you need to specify something that indicates where have to server to go.

What you can do here is put the code inside `userlogin.php` into your main view and, through a `cookie` or `session`, indicate from `.htaccess` if you have to show that code or not.

Using your actual rewrite rules:

```
// 1) Put your html code into main view

// 2) Change your link uri to /loginuser (remove .php)

// 3) In your .htaccess file, add this line:

    Rewrite rule ^loginuser$ /?login=1 [L]
```

`[L] Flag` indicates the Last instruction, no more code will be reached.

Hope helps.